# Why my "networkx" plot is inaccurate and does not visualize my input data?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-visualization

I'm trying to visualize a network topology with "networkx" library of Python. But the output is not accurate and is different than expected. Especially, the edges are not shown and the output plot is not organized and it is messy and inaccurate.

**My code:**

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re

f = open("topology.conf", "r")
G = nx.Graph()

flag = 111
root = ''
for line in f:
  for word in re.split(',|=| ', line):
    if flag == 0:
        root = word
        flag = 111
    if flag == 1:
        G.add_edge(root, word)
        flag = 111
    if word == 'SwitchName':
        flag = 0
        continue
    if word == 'Switches' or word == 'Nodes':
        flag = 1
        continue

nx.draw(G, with_labels=False)
plt.show()
f.close()
```

In the input data, which is related to a network topology, there is a connection between "SwitchName" and each item in "Switches" or "Nodes".

**Input data to be visualized:**

```
SwitchName=rootSwitch Switches=island1,island2,island3,island4
SwitchName=island1 Switches=r235u10ibs,r235u11ibs,r235u12ibs,r235u13ibs,r235u14ibs,r235u15ibs,r235u16ibs,r235u1ibs,r235u2ibs,r235u3ibs,r235u4ibs,r235u5ibs,r235u6ibs,r235u7ibs,r235u8ibs,r235u9ibs
SwitchName=island2 Switches=r252u10ibs,r252u11ibs,r252u12ibs,r252u13ibs,r252u14ibs,r252u15ibs,r252u16ibs,r252u1ibs,r252u2ibs,r252u3ibs,r252u4ibs,r252u5ibs,r252u6ibs,r252u7ibs,r252u8ibs,r252u9ibs
SwitchName=island3 Switches=r235u19ibs,r235u20ibs,r235u21ibs,r235u22ibs,r235u23ibs,r235u24ibs,r235u25ibs,r235u26ibs,r235u27ibs,r235u28ibs,r235u29ibs,r235u30ibs,r235u31ibs,r235u32ibs,r235u33ibs,r235u34ibs
SwitchName=island4 Switches=r252u19ibs,r252u20ibs,r252u21ibs,r252u22ibs,r252u23ibs,r252u24ibs,r252u25ibs,r252u26ibs,r252u27ibs,r252u28ibs,r252u29ibs,r252u30ibs,r252u31ibs,r252u32ibs,r252u33ibs,r252u34ibs
SwitchName=r252u20ibs Switches=r243u21ibl,r253u21ibl,r255u21ibl,r244u21ibl,r256u21ibl,r245u21ibl,r247u21ibl,r246u21ibl,r248u21ibl,r240u21ibl,r241u21ibl,r242u21ibl,r254u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u34ibs Switches=r229u21ibl,r231u21ibl,r232u21ibl,r223u21ibl,r225u21ibl,r224u21ibl,r226u21ibl,r236u21ibl,r227u21ibl,r237u21ibl,r239u21ibl,r228u21ibl,r238u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u12ibs Switches=r207u21ibl,r209u21ibl,r211u21ibl,r233u21ibl,r208u21ibl,r210u21ibl,r212u21ibl,r234u21ibl,r205u21ibl,r206u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u31ibs Switches=r243u21ibl,r253u21ibl,r255u21ibl,r244u21ibl,r256u21ibl,r245u21ibl,r247u21ibl,r246u21ibl,r248u21ibl,r240u21ibl,r241u21ibl,r242u21ibl,r254u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u28ibs Switches=r243u21ibl,r253u21ibl,r255u21ibl,r244u21ibl,r256u21ibl,r245u21ibl,r247u21ibl,r246u21ibl,r248u21ibl,r240u21ibl,r241u21ibl,r242u21ibl,r254u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u6ibs Switches=r219u21ibl,r221u21ibl,r222u21ibl,r213u21ibl,r214u21ibl,r250u21ibl,r215u21ibl,r217u21ibl,r249u21ibl,r251u21ibl,r216u21ibl,r218u21ibl,r220u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u23ibs Switches=r229u21ibl,r231u21ibl,r232u21ibl,r223u21ibl,r225u21ibl,r224u21ibl,r226u21ibl,r236u21ibl,r227u21ibl,r237u21ibl,r239u21ibl,r228u21ibl,r238u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u1ibs Switches=r207u21ibl,r209u21ibl,r211u21ibl,r233u21ibl,r208u21ibl,r210u21ibl,r212u21ibl,r234u21ibl,r205u21ibl,r206u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u33ibs Switches=r229u21ibl,r231u21ibl,r232u21ibl,r223u21ibl,r225u21ibl,r224u21ibl,r226u21ibl,r236u21ibl,r227u21ibl,r237u21ibl,r239u21ibl,r228u21ibl,r238u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u11ibs Switches=r207u21ibl,r209u21ibl,r211u21ibl,r233u21ibl,r208u21ibl,r210u21ibl,r212u21ibl,r234u21ibl,r205u21ibl,r206u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u9ibs Switches=r207u21ibl,r209u21ibl,r211u21ibl,r233u21ibl,r208u21ibl,r210u21ibl,r212u21ibl,r234u21ibl,r205u21ibl,r206u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u30ibs Switches=r243u21ibl,r253u21ibl,r255u21ibl,r244u21ibl,r256u21ibl,r245u21ibl,r247u21ibl,r246u21ibl,r248u21ibl,r240u21ibl,r241u21ibl,r242u21ibl,r254u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u27ibs Switches=r243u21ibl,r253u21ibl,r255u21ibl,r244u21ibl,r256u21ibl,r245u21ibl,r247u21ibl,r246u21ibl,r248u21ibl,r240u21ibl,r241u21ibl,r242u21ibl,r254u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u5ibs Switches=r219u21ibl,r221u21ibl,r222u21ibl,r213u21ibl,r214u21ibl,r250u21ibl,r215u21ibl,r217u21ibl,r249u21ibl,r251u21ibl,r216u21ibl,r218u21ibl,r220u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u19ibs Switches=r229u21ibl,r231u21ibl,r232u21ibl,r223u21ibl,r225u21ibl,r224u21ibl,r226u21ibl,r236u21ibl,r227u21ibl,r237u21ibl,r239u21ibl,r228u21ibl,r238u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u22ibs Switches=r229u21ibl,r231u21ibl,r232u21ibl,r223u21ibl,r225u21ibl,r224u21ibl,r226u21ibl,r236u21ibl,r227u21ibl,r237u21ibl,r239u21ibl,r228u21ibl,r238u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u10ibs Switches=r207u21ibl,r209u21ibl,r211u21ibl,r233u21ibl,r208u21ibl,r210u21ibl,r212u21ibl,r234u21ibl,r205u21ibl,r206u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u16ibs Switches=r219u21ibl,r221u21ibl,r222u21ibl,r213u21ibl,r214u21ibl,r250u21ibl,r215u21ibl,r217u21ibl,r249u21ibl,r251u21ibl,r216u21ibl,r218u21ibl,r220u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u8ibs Switches=r207u21ibl,r209u21ibl,r211u21ibl,r233u21ibl,r208u21ibl,r210u21ibl,r212u21ibl,r234u21ibl,r205u21ibl,r206u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u26ibs Switches=r243u21ibl,r253u21ibl,r255u21ibl,r244u21ibl,r256u21ibl,r245u21ibl,r247u21ibl,r246u21ibl,r248u21ibl,r240u21ibl,r241u21ibl,r242u21ibl,r254u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u4ibs Switches=r219u21ibl,r221u21ibl,r222u21ibl,r213u21ibl,r214u21ibl,r250u21ibl,r215u21ibl,r217u21ibl,r249u21ibl,r251u21ibl,r216u21ibl,r218u21ibl,r220u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u21ibs Switches=r229u21ibl,r231u21ibl,r232u21ibl,r223u21ibl,r225u21ibl,r224u21ibl,r226u21ibl,r236u21ibl,r227u21ibl,r237u21ibl,r239u21ibl,r228u21ibl,r238u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u15ibs Switches=r219u21ibl,r221u21ibl,r222u21ibl,r213u21ibl,r214u21ibl,r250u21ibl,r215u21ibl,r217u21ibl,r249u21ibl,r251u21ibl,r218u21ibl,r216u21ibl,r220u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u32ibs Switches=r229u21ibl,r231u21ibl,r232u21ibl,r223u21ibl,r225u21ibl,r224u21ibl,r226u21ibl,r236u21ibl,r227u21ibl,r237u21ibl,r239u21ibl,r228u21ibl,r238u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u29ibs Switches=r229u21ibl,r231u21ibl,r232u21ibl,r223u21ibl,r225u21ibl,r224u21ibl,r226u21ibl,r236u21ibl,r227u21ibl,r237u21ibl,r239u21ibl,r228u21ibl,r238u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u7ibs Switches=r207u21ibl,r209u21ibl,r211u21ibl,r233u21ibl,r208u21ibl,r210u21ibl,r212u21ibl,r234u21ibl,r205u21ibl,r206u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u25ibs Switches=r243u21ibl,r253u21ibl,r255u21ibl,r244u21ibl,r256u21ibl,r245u21ibl,r247u21ibl,r246u21ibl,r248u21ibl,r240u21ibl,r241u21ibl,r242u21ibl,r254u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u3ibs Switches=r219u21ibl,r221u21ibl,r222u21ibl,r213u21ibl,r214u21ibl,r250u21ibl,r215u21ibl,r217u21ibl,r249u21ibl,r251u21ibl,r216u21ibl,r218u21ibl,r220u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u20ibs Switches=r229u21ibl,r231u21ibl,r232u21ibl,r223u21ibl,r225u21ibl,r224u21ibl,r226u21ibl,r236u21ibl,r227u21ibl,r237u21ibl,r239u21ibl,r228u21ibl,r238u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u14ibs Switches=r219u21ibl,r221u21ibl,r222u21ibl,r213u21ibl,r214u21ibl,r250u21ibl,r215u21ibl,r217u21ibl,r249u21ibl,r251u21ibl,r216u21ibl,r218u21ibl,r220u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u31ibs Switches=r229u21ibl,r231u21ibl,r232u21ibl,r223u21ibl,r225u21ibl,r224u21ibl,r226u21ibl,r236u21ibl,r227u21ibl,r237u21ibl,r239u21ibl,r228u21ibl,r238u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u28ibs Switches=r229u21ibl,r231u21ibl,r232u21ibl,r223u21ibl,r225u21ibl,r224u21ibl,r226u21ibl,r236u21ibl,r227u21ibl,r237u21ibl,r239u21ibl,r228u21ibl,r238u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u6ibs Switches=r207u21ibl,r209u21ibl,r211u21ibl,r233u21ibl,r208u21ibl,r210u21ibl,r212u21ibl,r234u21ibl,r205u21ibl,r206u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u16ibs Switches=r207u21ibl,r209u21ibl,r211u21ibl,r233u21ibl,r208u21ibl,r210u21ibl,r212u21ibl,r234u21ibl,r205u21ibl,r206u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u13ibs Switches=r219u21ibl,r221u21ibl,r222u21ibl,r213u21ibl,r214u21ibl,r250u21ibl,r215u21ibl,r217u21ibl,r249u21ibl,r251u21ibl,r216u21ibl,r218u21ibl,r220u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u30ibs Switches=r229u21ibl,r231u21ibl,r232u21ibl,r223u21ibl,r225u21ibl,r224u21ibl,r226u21ibl,r236u21ibl,r227u21ibl,r237u21ibl,r239u21ibl,r228u21ibl,r238u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u27ibs Switches=r229u21ibl,r231u21ibl,r232u21ibl,r223u21ibl,r225u21ibl,r224u21ibl,r226u21ibl,r236u21ibl,r227u21ibl,r237u21ibl,r239u21ibl,r228u21ibl,r238u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u24ibs Switches=r243u21ibl,r253u21ibl,r255u21ibl,r244u21ibl,r256u21ibl,r245u21ibl,r247u21ibl,r246u21ibl,r248u21ibl,r240u21ibl,r241u21ibl,r242u21ibl,r254u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u2ibs Switches=r219u21ibl,r221u21ibl,r222u21ibl,r213u21ibl,r214u21ibl,r250u21ibl,r215u21ibl,r217u21ibl,r249u21ibl,r251u21ibl,r216u21ibl,r218u21ibl,r220u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u34ibs Switches=r243u21ibl,r253u21ibl,r255u21ibl,r244u21ibl,r256u21ibl,r245u21ibl,r247u21ibl,r246u21ibl,r248u21ibl,r240u21ibl,r241u21ibl,r242u21ibl,r254u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u9ibs Switches=r219u21ibl,r221u21ibl,r222u21ibl,r213u21ibl,r214u21ibl,r250u21ibl,r215u21ibl,r217u21ibl,r249u21ibl,r251u21ibl,r216u21ibl,r218u21ibl,r220u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u12ibs Switches=r219u21ibl,r221u21ibl,r222u21ibl,r213u21ibl,r214u21ibl,r250u21ibl,r215u21ibl,r217u21ibl,r249u21ibl,r251u21ibl,r216u21ibl,r218u21ibl,r220u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u26ibs Switches=r229u21ibl,r231u21ibl,r232u21ibl,r223u21ibl,r225u21ibl,r224u21ibl,r226u21ibl,r236u21ibl,r227u21ibl,r237u21ibl,r239u21ibl,r228u21ibl,r238u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u5ibs Switches=r207u21ibl,r209u21ibl,r211u21ibl,r233u21ibl,r208u21ibl,r210u21ibl,r212u21ibl,r234u21ibl,r205u21ibl,r206u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u23ibs Switches=r243u21ibl,r253u21ibl,r255u21ibl,r244u21ibl,r256u21ibl,r245u21ibl,r247u21ibl,r246u21ibl,r248u21ibl,r240u21ibl,r241u21ibl,r242u21ibl,r254u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u1ibs Switches=r219u21ibl,r221u21ibl,r222u21ibl,r213u21ibl,r214u21ibl,r250u21ibl,r215u21ibl,r217u21ibl,r249u21ibl,r251u21ibl,r216u21ibl,r218u21ibl,r220u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u15ibs Switches=r207u21ibl,r209u21ibl,r211u21ibl,r233u21ibl,r208u21ibl,r210u21ibl,r212u21ibl,r234u21ibl,r205u21ibl,r206u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u11ibs Switches=r219u21ibl,r221u21ibl,r222u21ibl,r213u21ibl,r214u21ibl,r250u21ibl,r215u21ibl,r217u21ibl,r249u21ibl,r251u21ibl,r216u21ibl,r218u21ibl,r220u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u25ibs Switches=r229u21ibl,r231u21ibl,r232u21ibl,r223u21ibl,r225u21ibl,r224u21ibl,r226u21ibl,r236u21ibl,r227u21ibl,r237u21ibl,r239u21ibl,r228u21ibl,r238u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u4ibs Switches=r207u21ibl,r209u21ibl,r211u21ibl,r233u21ibl,r208u21ibl,r210u21ibl,r212u21ibl,r234u21ibl,r205u21ibl,r206u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u19ibs Switches=r243u21ibl,r253u21ibl,r255u21ibl,r244u21ibl,r256u21ibl,r245u21ibl,r247u21ibl,r246u21ibl,r248u21ibl,r240u21ibl,r241u21ibl,r242u21ibl,r254u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u22ibs Switches=r243u21ibl,r253u21ibl,r255u21ibl,r244u21ibl,r256u21ibl,r245u21ibl,r247u21ibl,r246u21ibl,r248u21ibl,r240u21ibl,r241u21ibl,r242u21ibl,r254u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u14ibs Switches=r207u21ibl,r209u21ibl,r211u21ibl,r233u21ibl,r208u21ibl,r210u21ibl,r212u21ibl,r234u21ibl,r205u21ibl,r206u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u33ibs Switches=r243u21ibl,r253u21ibl,r255u21ibl,r244u21ibl,r256u21ibl,r245u21ibl,r247u21ibl,r246u21ibl,r248u21ibl,r240u21ibl,r241u21ibl,r242u21ibl,r254u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u24ibs Switches=r229u21ibl,r231u21ibl,r232u21ibl,r223u21ibl,r225u21ibl,r224u21ibl,r226u21ibl,r236u21ibl,r227u21ibl,r237u21ibl,r239u21ibl,r228u21ibl,r238u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u8ibs Switches=r219u21ibl,r221u21ibl,r222u21ibl,r213u21ibl,r214u21ibl,r250u21ibl,r215u21ibl,r217u21ibl,r249u21ibl,r251u21ibl,r216u21ibl,r218u21ibl,r220u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u3ibs Switches=r207u21ibl,r209u21ibl,r211u21ibl,r233u21ibl,r208u21ibl,r210u21ibl,r212u21ibl,r234u21ibl,r205u21ibl,r206u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u21ibs Switches=r243u21ibl,r253u21ibl,r255u21ibl,r244u21ibl,r256u21ibl,r245u21ibl,r247u21ibl,r246u21ibl,r248u21ibl,r240u21ibl,r241u21ibl,r242u21ibl,r254u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u13ibs Switches=r207u21ibl,r209u21ibl,r211u21ibl,r233u21ibl,r208u21ibl,r210u21ibl,r212u21ibl,r234u21ibl,r205u21ibl,r206u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u32ibs Switches=r243u21ibl,r253u21ibl,r255u21ibl,r244u21ibl,r256u21ibl,r245u21ibl,r247u21ibl,r246u21ibl,r248u21ibl,r240u21ibl,r241u21ibl,r242u21ibl,r254u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u29ibs Switches=r243u21ibl,r253u21ibl,r255u21ibl,r244u21ibl,r256u21ibl,r245u21ibl,r247u21ibl,r246u21ibl,r248u21ibl,r240u21ibl,r241u21ibl,r242u21ibl,r254u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u10ibs Switches=r219u21ibl,r221u21ibl,r222u21ibl,r213u21ibl,r214u21ibl,r250u21ibl,r215u21ibl,r217u21ibl,r249u21ibl,r251u21ibl,r216u21ibl,r218u21ibl,r220u21ibl
SwitchName=r252u7ibs Switches=r219u21ibl,r221u21ibl,r222u21ibl,r213u21ibl,r214u21ibl,r250u21ibl,r215u21ibl,r217u21ibl,r249u21ibl,r251u21ibl,r216u21ibl,r218u21ibl,r220u21ibl
SwitchName=r235u2ibs Switches=r207u21ibl,r209u21ibl,r211u21ibl,r233u21ibl,r208u21ibl,r210u21ibl,r212u21ibl,r234u21ibl,r205u21ibl,r206u21ibl
SwitchName=r240u21ibl Nodes=r240n01,r240n02,r240n03,r240n04,r240n05,r240n06,r240n07,r240n08,r240n09,r240n10,r240n11,r240n12,r240n13,r240n14,r240n15,r240n16,r240n17,r240n18,r240n19,r240n20
SwitchName=r229u21ibl Nodes=r229n01,r229n02,r229n03,r229n04,r229n05,r229n06,r229n07,r229n08,r229n09,r229n10,r229n11,r229n12,r229n13,r229n14,r229n15,r229n16,r229n17,r229n18,r229n19,r229n20
SwitchName=r219u21ibl Nodes=r219n01,r219n02,r219n03,r219n04,r219n05,r219n06,r219n07,r219n08,r219n09,r219n10,r219n11,r219n12,r219n13,r219n14,r219n15,r219n16,r219n17,r219n18,r219n19,r219n20
SwitchName=r207u21ibl Nodes=r207n01,r207n02,r207n03,r207n04,r207n06,r207n05,r207n07,r207n08,r207n09,r207n10,r207n11,r207n12,r207n13,r207n14,r207n15,r207n16,r207n17,r207n18,r207n19,r207n20
SwitchName=r209u21ibl Nodes=r209n01,r209n02,r209n03,r209n04,r209n05,r209n06,r209n07,r209n08,r209n09,r209n10,r209n11,r209n12,r209n13,r209n14,r209n15,r209n16,r209n17,r209n18,r209n19,r209n20
SwitchName=r249u21ibl Nodes=r249n01,r249n02,r249n03,r249n04,r249n05,r249n06,r249n07,r249n08,r249n09,r249n10,r249n11,r249n12,r249n13,r249n14,r249n15,r249n16,r249n17,r249n18,r249n19,r249n20
SwitchName=r237u21ibl Nodes=r237n01,r237n02,r237n03,r237n04,r237n05,r237n06,r237n07,r237n08,r237n09,r237n10,r237n11,r237n12,r237n13,r237n14,r237n15,r237n16,r237n17,r237n18,r237n19,r237n20
SwitchName=r239u21ibl Nodes=r239n01,r239n02,r239n03,r239n04,r239n05,r239n07,r239n06,r239n08,r239n09,r239n10,r239n11,r239n12,r239n13,r239n14,r239n15,r239n16,r239n17,r239n18,r239n19,r239n20
SwitchName=r227u21ibl Nodes=r227n01,r227n02,r227n03,r227n04,r227n05,r227n06,r227n07,r227n08,r227n10,r227n11,r227n12,r227n13,r227n14,r227n16,r227n17,r227n18,r227n19,r227n20,r227n09,r227n15
SwitchName=r215u21ibl Nodes=r215n01,r215n02,r215n03,r215n04,r215n05,r215n06,r215n07,r215n08,r215n09,r215n10,r215n11,r215n12,r215n13,r215n14,r215n15,r215n16,r215n17,r215n18,r215n19,r215n20
SwitchName=r217u21ibl Nodes=r217n01,r217n02,r217n03,r217n04,r217n05,r217n06,r217n07,r217n08,r217n09,r217n10,r217n11,r217n12,r217n13,r217n14,r217n15,r217n16,r217n17,r217n18,r217n19,r217n20
SwitchName=r205u21ibl Nodes=r205n01,r205n02,r205n03,r205n04,r205n05,r205n06,r205n07,r205n08,r205n09,r205n10,r205n12,r205n11,r205n13,r205n14,r205n15,r205n16,r205n17,r205n18,r205n19,r205n20
SwitchName=r245u21ibl Nodes=r245n01,r245n02,r245n03,r245n04,r245n05,r245n06,r245n07,r245n08,r245n09,r245n10,r245n11,r245n12,r245n13,r245n14,r245n15,r245n16,r245n17,r245n18,r245n19,r245n20
SwitchName=r247u21ibl Nodes=r247n01,r247n02,r247n03,r247n04,r247n05,r247n06,r247n07,r247n08,r247n09,r247n10,r247n11,r247n12,r247n13,r247n14,r247n15,r247n16,r247n17,r247n18,r247n19,r247n20
SwitchName=r223u21ibl Nodes=r223n01,r223n02,r223n03,r223n04,r223n05,r223n06,r223n07,r223n08,r223n09,r223n10,r223n11,r223n12,r223n13,r223n14,r223n15,r223n16,r223n17,r223n18,r223n19,r223n20
SwitchName=r225u21ibl Nodes=r225n01,r225n02,r225n04,r225n03,r225n05,r225n06,r225n07,r225n08,r225n09,r225n10,r225n11,r225n12,r225n13,r225n14,r225n15,r225n16,r225n17,r225n18,r225n19,r225n20
SwitchName=r213u21ibl Nodes=r213n01,r213n02,r213n03,r213n04,r213n05,r213n06,r213n07,r213n08,r213n09,r213n10,r213n11,r213n12,r213n13,r213n14,r213n15,r213n16,r213n17,r213n18,r213n19,r213n20
SwitchName=r253u21ibl Nodes=r253n01,r253n02,r253n03,r253n04,r253n05,r253n06,r253n07,r253n08,r253n09,r253n10,r253n11,r253n12,r253n13,r253n14,r253n15,r253n16,r253n17,r253n18,r253n19,r253n20
SwitchName=r255u21ibl Nodes=r255n01,r255n02,r255n03,r255n04,r255n05,r255n06,r255n07,r255n08,r255n09,r255n10,r255n11,r255n12,r255n13,r255n14,r255n15,r255n16,r255n17,r255n18,r255n19,r255n20
SwitchName=r243u21ibl Nodes=r243n01,r243n02,r243n03,r243n04,r243n05,r243n06,r243n07,r243n08,r243n09,r243n10,r243n11,r243n12,r243n13,r243n14,r243n15,r243n16,r243n17,r243n18,r243n19,r243n20
SwitchName=r231u21ibl Nodes=r231n01,r231n02,r231n03,r231n04,r231n05,r231n06,r231n07,r231n08,r231n09,r231n10,r231n11,r231n12,r231n13,r231n14,r231n15,r231n16,r231n17,r231n18,r231n19,r231n20
SwitchName=r233u21ibl Nodes=r233n01,r233n02,r233n03,r233n04,r233n05,r233n06,r233n07,r233n08,r233n09,r233n10,r233n11,r233n12,r233n13,r233n14,r233n15,r233n16,r233n17,r233n18,r233n19,r233n20
SwitchName=r221u21ibl Nodes=r221n01,r221n02,r221n03,r221n04,r221n05,r221n06,r221n07,r221n08,r221n09,r221n10,r221n11,r221n12,r221n13,r221n14,r221n15,r221n16,r221n17,r221n18,r221n19,r221n20
SwitchName=r211u21ibl Nodes=r211n01,r211n02,r211n03,r211n04,r211n05,r211n06,r211n07,r211n08,r211n09,r211n10,r211n11,r211n12,r211n13,r211n14,r211n15,r211n16,r211n17,r211n18,r211n19,r211n20
SwitchName=r251u21ibl Nodes=r251n01,r251n02,r251n03,r251n04,r251n05,r251n06,r251n07,r251n08,r251n09,r251n10,r251n11,r251n12,r251n13,r251n14,r251n15,r251n16,r251n17,r251n18,r251n19,r251n20
SwitchName=r241u21ibl Nodes=r241n01,r241n02,r241n03,r241n04,r241n05,r241n06,r241n07,r241n08,r241n09,r241n10,r241n11,r241n12,r241n13,r241n14,r241n15,r241n16,r241n17,r241n18,r241n19,r241n20
SwitchName=r208u21ibl Nodes=r208n01,r208n02,r208n03,r208n04,r208n05,r208n06,r208n07,r208n08,r208n09,r208n10,r208n11,r208n12,r208n13,r208n14,r208n15,r208n16,r208n17,r208n18,r208n19,r208n20
SwitchName=r238u21ibl Nodes=r238n01,r238n02,r238n03,r238n04,r238n05,r238n06,r238n07,r238n08,r238n09,r238n10,r238n11,r238n12,r238n13,r238n14,r238n15,r238n16,r238n17,r238n18,r238n19,r238n20
SwitchName=r228u21ibl Nodes=r228n01,r228n03,r228n02,r228n04,r228n05,r228n06,r228n07,r228n09,r228n10,r228n08,r228n11,r228n12,r228n13,r228n14,r228n15,r228n16,r228n17,r228n18,r228n19,r228n20
SwitchName=r216u21ibl Nodes=r216n01,r216n02,r216n03,r216n04,r216n05,r216n06,r216n07,r216n08,r216n09,r216n10,r216n11,r216n12,r216n13,r216n14,r216n15,r216n16,r216n17,r216n18,r216n19,r216n20
SwitchName=r218u21ibl Nodes=r218n01,r218n02,r218n03,r218n04,r218n05,r218n06,r218n07,r218n08,r218n09,r218n10,r218n11,r218n12,r218n13,r218n14,r218n15,r218n16,r218n17,r218n18,r218n19,r218n20
SwitchName=r206u21ibl Nodes=r206n01,r206n02,r206n03,r206n04,r206n05,r206n06,r206n07,r206n08,r206n09,r206n10,r206n11,r206n12,r206n13,r206n14,r206n15,r206n16,r206n17,r206n18,r206n19,r206n20
SwitchName=r246u21ibl Nodes=r246n01,r246n02,r246n03,r246n04,r246n05,r246n06,r246n07,r246n08,r246n09,r246n10,r246n11,r246n12,r246n13,r246n14,r246n15,r246n16,r246n17,r246n18,r246n19,r246n20
SwitchName=r248u21ibl Nodes=r248n01,r248n02,r248n03,r248n04,r248n05,r248n06,r248n07,r248n08,r248n09,r248n10,r248n11,r248n12,r248n13,r248n14,r248n15,r248n16,r248n17,r248n18,r248n19,r248n20
SwitchName=r236u21ibl Nodes=r236n01,r236n02,r236n03,r236n04,r236n05,r236n06,r236n07,r236n08,r236n09,r236n10,r236n11,r236n12,r236n13,r236n14,r236n15,r236n16,r236n17,r236n18,r236n19,r236n20
SwitchName=r224u21ibl Nodes=r224n01,r224n02,r224n03,r224n04,r224n05,r224n06,r224n07,r224n08,r224n09,r224n10,r224n11,r224n12,r224n13,r224n14,r224n15,r224n16,r224n17,r224n18,r224n19,r224n20
SwitchName=r226u21ibl Nodes=r226n01,r226n02,r226n03,r226n04,r226n05,r226n06,r226n08,r226n07,r226n09,r226n10,r226n11,r226n12,r226n13,r226n14,r226n15,r226n16,r226n17,r226n18,r226n19,r226n20
SwitchName=r214u21ibl Nodes=r214n01,r214n02,r214n03,r214n04,r214n05,r214n06,r214n07,r214n08,r214n09,r214n10,r214n11,r214n12,r214n14,r214n13,r214n15,r214n16,r214n17,r214n19,r214n18,r214n20
SwitchName=r256u21ibl Nodes=r256n01,r256n02,r256n03,r256n04,r256n05,r256n06,r256n07,r256n08,r256n09,r256n10,r256n11,r256n12,r256n13,r256n14,r256n15,r256n16,r256n17,r256n18,r256n19,r256n20
SwitchName=r244u21ibl Nodes=r244n01,r244n02,r244n03,r244n04,r244n05,r244n06,r244n08,r244n07,r244n09,r244n10,r244n11,r244n12,r244n13,r244n14,r244n15,r244n16,r244n17,r244n18,r244n19,r244n20
SwitchName=r232u21ibl Nodes=r232n01,r232n02,r232n03,r232n04,r232n05,r232n06,r232n07,r232n08,r232n09,r232n10,r232n11,r232n12,r232n13,r232n14,r232n15,r232n16,r232n17,r232n18,r232n19,r232n20
SwitchName=r234u21ibl Nodes=r234n01,r234n02,r234n03,r234n04,r234n05,r234n06,r234n07,r234n08,r234n09,r234n10,r234n11,r234n12,r234n13,r234n14,r234n15,r234n16,r234n17,r234n18,r234n19,r234n20
SwitchName=r222u21ibl Nodes=r222n01,r222n02,r222n03,r222n04,r222n05,r222n06,r222n07,r222n08,r222n09,r222n10,r222n11,r222n12,r222n13,r222n14,r222n15,r222n16,r222n17,r222n18,r222n19,r222n20
SwitchName=r210u21ibl Nodes=r210n01,r210n02,r210n03,r210n04,r210n05,r210n06,r210n07,r210n08,r210n10,r210n09,r210n11,r210n12,r210n13,r210n14,r210n15,r210n16,r210n17,r210n18,r210n19,r210n20
SwitchName=r212u21ibl Nodes=r212n01,r212n02,r212n03,r212n04,r212n05,r212n06,r212n11,r212n12,r212n09,r212n10,r212n07,r212n08,r212n13,r212n14,r212n15,r212n16,r212n17,r212n18,r212n19,r212n20
SwitchName=r254u21ibl Nodes=r254n01,r254n02,r254n03,r254n04,r254n05,r254n06,r254n07,r254n08,r254n09,r254n10,r254n11,r254n12,r254n13,r254n14,r254n15,r254n16,r254n17,r254n18,r254n19,r254n20
SwitchName=r242u21ibl Nodes=r242n01,r242n02,r242n03,r242n04,r242n05,r242n06,r242n07,r242n08,r242n09,r242n10,r242n11,r242n12,r242n13,r242n14,r242n15,r242n16,r242n18,r242n17,r242n19,r242n20
SwitchName=r220u21ibl Nodes=r220n01,r220n02,r220n03,r220n04,r220n05,r220n06,r220n07,r220n08,r220n09,r220n10,r220n11,r220n12,r220n13,r220n14,r220n15,r220n16,r220n17,r220n19,r220n18,r220n20
SwitchName=r250u21ibl Nodes=r250n01,r250n02,r250n04,r250n03,r250n05,r250n06,r250n07,r250n08,r250n09,r250n10,r250n11,r250n12,r250n13,r250n14,r250n15,r250n16,r250n18,r250n17,r250n19,r250n20
```

Finally, the output file is expected to be like the following (not exactly the same, but something similar in the case of format)

**Expected output**

[image: A sample output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your parsing. You can check it by printing all the edges (by adding line `[e for e in G.edges]`) in your code. Here is the sample that will solve the problem:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re

f = open("topology.conf", "r")
G = nx.Graph()

for line in f:
    seg = re.split(' ', line)
    sources = re.split('=', seg[0])
    source = sources[1]
    
    for word in re.split(',|=| ', seg[1]):
        if word == 'Switches' or word == 'Nodes':
            continue
        G.add_edge(source, word.strip())

nx.draw(G, with_labels=False)
plt.show()
f.close()

# [e for e in G.edges]
```

Here is the sample output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Now the only problem is the size of the dots, which are very big. Do you think there is a way to plot them in small sizes?

Comment: I would suggest you to try with a smaller graph.